# Merging SVG together

Tags: svg

I have a SVG which renders some content as below (svg-1),

```
----------------
| (Image)  Text|
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|         Text |
----------------
```

I have a Seperate set of Svg documents which have some content in it as below (svg-2)

```
----------------
|              |
|              |
| Some Content |
| here         | 
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
----------------
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get a combined svg similar to below

```
----------------
| (Image)  Text|
|              |
| Some Content |
| here         |
|              |
|              |
|         Text |
----------------
```

I belive the href tag could be something that can be used here but wasnt very sure on if that was the best approach or how exaclt to implement it.

Here is the code for the svg-01 also named as svg01.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<svg width="200mm" height="300mm"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" dominant-baseline="hanging">
    <image x="1.74mm" y="1.59mm" height="19.97mm" width="23.41mm" href=".."/>
    <text x="139.85mm" y="1.85mm" font-size="12pt">Text</text>
    <text x="142.05mm" y="289.72mm" font-size="12pt">Text</text>
</svg>
```

Here is my code for the attempted combined svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<svg width="300mm" height="200mm"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink>
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" dominant-baseline="hanging">
    <image xlink:href="svg01.svg" />
    <text x="43.12mm" y="50.54mm" width="73.98mm" height="8.41mm" font-size="12pt">Some Content here</text>
</svg>
```

Is this behaviour possible in svg

What is the best approach of achieving my requirement ? Does svg provide any sort of templating functionality ?
Would really appreciate some help here

Comment: Your question is unclear, you want to merge the content but when someone actually does that in an answer you say that wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: Well I want to merge two seperate svgs together by linking them . Not creating a whole new SVG by combining the two

Answer (score 1):

If your SVGs are the same size, you can just take the content of each and combine it like so. You may have to adjust things if your SVGs are different sizes or have different view boxes.

First SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<svg width="200mm" height="300mm"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" dominant-baseline="hanging">
    <image x="1.74mm" y="1.59mm" height="19.97mm" width="23.41mm" href=".."/>
    <text x="139.85mm" y="1.85mm" font-size="12pt">Text</text>
    <text x="142.05mm" y="289.72mm" font-size="12pt">Text</text>
</svg>
```

Second SVG

```
<svg width="200mm" height="300mm"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink>
    <text x="43.12mm" y="50.54mm" width="73.98mm" height="8.41mm" font-size="12pt">Some Content here</text>
</svg>
```

Combined SVG

```
<svg width="200mm" height="300mm"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" dominant-baseline="hanging">

    <!-- Content from first SVG -->
    <image x="1.74mm" y="1.59mm" height="19.97mm" width="23.41mm" href=".."/>
    <text x="139.85mm" y="1.85mm" font-size="12pt">Text</text>
    <text x="142.05mm" y="289.72mm" font-size="12pt">Text</text>

    <!-- Content from second SVG -->
    <text x="43.12mm" y="50.54mm" width="73.98mm" height="8.41mm" font-size="12pt">Some Content here</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yeah but here you have basically created  a new svg with the content in the fist and second .
My requirement is in a world where the I cant have a seperate file names combinedsvg but I want to merge the content together in the first and second svg @Burgan